# AJAX FormData object explanation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am using ajax FormData object to insert multipart/form-data. But my **Headache** is that i am still unable to understand why **`[0]`** is used in it.what does it mean?

**my code:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#but").click(function(){
                var formData = new FormData($("#myform")[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    url : "test.php",
                    type : "POST",
                    dataType : "html",
                    data : formData,
                    contentType : false,
                    processData : false,
                    success : function(res){
                        $('div.result').html(res);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        </script>
```

Could someone explain FormData object?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery selectors return arrays of matching elements.

`[0]`, or `.get(0)`, reaches in and returns a native reference to the first of those matched elements.

The `formData()` constructor expects as its only argument a form object, hence.